# Custom function to update stock values from two different variable products

Tags: woocommerce, stock

I read around the web and didn't find valid solutions to my problem (if they do exist).

I have 2 variable products: they are sailing cruises. Each variation is a calendar week. Stocks represents places available on boat.

product_1 = standard prices

product_2 = student prices

Variations are the same for both products (as the sailing weeks are the same), prices change. **I have the necessity of considering them as two distinct products** (so please avoid suggesting solutions such as bulk products - chained products- more variations in product etc).

I want to keep the basic stock management on product_1, while I would like not to manage any stock on product_2. However I would like to write a function which basically says:

```
 if ($variation_id of $product_2 is in the order)
    {
    $update_stock_variation_id =
   (stock of $variation_id in $product_1) - ($quantity_product_2 in order) 

    }
```

Do you think is it possible?

Thank you for your inputs